# Pass data from Azure DevOps release to release tab

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

I am developing an extension for Azure DevOps. Details of my extension are as below

Supported environment

- Azure DevOps
- TFS 2017
- TFS 2018
- DevOps server 2019
- DevOps server 2020

Language: Typescript

Contribution Points :

- ms.vss-distributed-task.task
- ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-summary-tab

Scopes :

- vso.build
- vso.build_execute
- vso.work_write
- vso.release
- vso.release_execute

My task is running in the release pipeline and generates some data. I want to pass these data to the release tab once the release is completed. And display some arranged information in the release tab. further user should able to view information related to a particular old release in the tab by navigating to that relase as well.

Please be kind enough to provide some guidelines for achieving this task. Please let me know if you need any additional information.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ideas for getting data from release pipeline:

1. Present the data you need in the task's running log and then use REST APIs to get the log. Here are several REST APIs:

[Releases - Get Task Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20task%20log?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0): This REST API can get log of a specific task, which only supports plain texts.

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}/deployPhases/{releaseDeployPhaseId}/tasks/{taskId}/logs?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

[Releases - Get Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20logs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0): This REST API download a zip file that contains log of all the tasks.

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/logs?api-version=6.0-preview.2
```

2. Write the data you need to a file and then use [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to get the file outside the release.

Comment: Thank you Jane Ma the second example is not possible as we are not planning to use an external source to save this data. Could you kindly able to provide me a sample for the first scenario (data retrieval part).I assume that I will have to use azure-devops-node-api